# Disable auto-hide of scrollbar in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, scrollbar

I work as second-line support, a user came up with a intriguing issue. He has a Microsoft SurfacePro with Win10 (1607 Anniversary Update) and Office 2016 installed.

In Outlook, in the Reading Pane, the vertical scrollbar keeps disappearing. Unless an email is specifically highlighted.  What I have tried from my end is

- Disabled "Smooth-scroll list boxes" in Adjust Appearance and Performance of Windows.
- Disabled Hardware Acceleration in Outlook

It still doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's been like that since [Outlook 2013](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/how-to-disable-the-auto-hide-feature-of-vertical/66d1efd6-0824-47fc-8980-f31f5a7e54b5). MS doesn't seem to want to fix it.

Comment: In Mozilla Firefox, I've seen a similar problem. Closing the program and opening it again opens with the scroll bar.  So that's something to try.